# How do you find and display the peak elements in a multidimensional array (matrix)? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm just starting out with C++, and I'm trying to get the hang of things. In one of the courses I'm taking, I'm tasked with a project that requires me to analyze a predetermined array for peak elements (elements which are greater than any of its neighbours), and to only display the peak elements (leave the spaces for non-peak elements blank). The way i have done this is by creating two separate arrays, with one holding the integer values and another holding a boolean value for if the element is a peak element. However, I seem to have a problem with my function that displays my array. Even when I change the display condition to false, the value assigned to all the elements by default, nothing appears when I compile and execute it. Furthermore, if someone could inform me of a more efficient way to determine the peak elements other than my horrifically complicated if statements, that would be awesome. Some help would be greatly appreciated! ^_^

P.S. I am limited to using the stdio.h and genlib.h libraries only for this project, and I'm sorry in advance if my formatting is a bit wonky; it's my first post..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "genlib.h"

#define size 5

void ComputeArray(int MainArray[size][size], bool IfShown[size][size]); 
void DisplayArray(int MainArray[size][size], bool IfShown[size][size]);

int main()
{
int i, i2;
int MainArray[size][size]=
{
    {-32767,-32767,-32767,-32767,-32767},
    {-32767,3,2,9,-32767},
    {-32767,13,7,6,-32767},
    {-32767,1,5,8,-32767},
    {-32767,-32767,-32767,-32767,-32767}
};
bool IfShown[size][size];
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for (i2=0;i2<size;i2++)
    {
        IfShown[i][i2]=false;
    }
}
ComputeArray(MainArray, IfShown);
DisplayArray(MainArray, IfShown);   
}

void ComputeArray(int MainArray[size][size], bool IfShown[size][size]) 
{
int i, i2, j, j2;

for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{   
    for (i2=0;i2<size;i2++)
    {       
        for(j=i-1;j<=i+1;j++);
        {
            for(j2=i2-1;j2<=i2+1;j2++);
            {
                if(MainArray[i][i2]>MainArray[j][j2]) IfShown[i][i2]=true;
            }
        }

    }
}
}

void DisplayArray(int MainArray[size][size], bool IfShown[size][size])
{
int i, i2;

for (i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for (i2=0;i2<size;i2++)
    {
        if(IfShown[i][i2]==true)
        {
            printf("%d\t", MainArray[i][i2]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\t");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: You are passing the arrays by value, not by reference (use a pointer). a `max(max(data[x-1][y], data[x+1][y]), max(data[x][y-1],data[x][y+1]))` would have found the max element in a one liner.

Comment: @HerpDerpington What dialect of C++ do you use? Arrays as formal parameters are passed as addresses; not by value (or to be accurate, their "value" is an address in the OP's code). So what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: If you are trying to understand how to find the greatest element in an array. You simply take two elements and compare them if it`s < or == or >, you can only compare two elements at a time, so you create a temporary variable that will hold the current greatest element. Now you need to compare this greatest element you have seen so far with the third element. If the 3rd element is greater than your temp element then the 3rd element becomes your greatest element. You do this until you reach the end of the array. Once you a done, create a new array and store all your greatest in this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that displays your array is the least of your worries.

Your use of the improper assignment where you should be using logical equality evaluation or some other boolean condition evaluation is **rampant** in this code. such as:

```
for (i=0;i=size;i++)
```

should be

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++) // see < in place of =
```

Further below, there are mountains of improper assignments where there should be comparisons, such as:

```
if (MainArray[i][i2]=MainArray[0][0])
```

should be

```
if (MainArray[i][i2] == MainArray[0][0])
```

In total, there are some **17** such instances through this code. You need a refresher on what operators in C++ do and how to call them. While fixing that, declare `main()` as `int main()` please.

Comment: i fixed the problems you indicated and then changed the code for simplicity's sake. However, it still fails to give the correct array